# CoreText: Invalid 'kern' Subtable In CTFont

Tags: ios, core-text

I am using a custom font applied to a CATextLayer. I am using the tutorial and sample code found here. http://www.freetimestudios.com/2010/09/13/custom-fonts-on-the-ipad-and-ios-4/

However, every so often, I get the following error. Nothing in particular seems to trigger it. Can someone shed some light as to what this means? What to check for?

```
CoreText: Invalid 'kern' Subtable In CTFont <name: Intellect, size: 20.000000, matrix: 0x0>
CTFontDescriptor <attributes: <CFDictionary 0xac07a80 [0x38295d98]>{type = mutable, count = 1, capacity = 3, pairs = (
    0 : <CFString 0x3833f750 [0x38295d98]>{contents = "NSFontNameAttribute"} = <CFString 0x159af0 [0x38295d98]>{contents = "Intellect"}
```

I load the font using the following code. This code is taken from the project in the link above.

```
- (CTFontRef)newCustomFontWithName:(NSString *)fontName
                            ofType:(NSString *)type
                        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fontName ofType:type];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];
    CGDataProviderRef fontProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    [data release];

    CGFontRef cgFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontProvider);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontProvider);

    CTFontDescriptorRef fontDescriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((CFDictionaryRef)attributes);
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(cgFont, 0, NULL, fontDescriptor);
    CFRelease(fontDescriptor);
    CGFontRelease(cgFont);
    return font;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validating the installed font showed there was a problem with the fonts "kern" values. This was what was causing the problem.

Comment: So did the validation fix it?

Comment: @Ralphleon No it did not. I had to download the font from another site, validate, and make sure it was fine. The kern I believe has to do with the spacing, sometimes a problem with a custom font.

Comment: I have this problem. Except validations pass. I'm using OpenSans by the way...anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Also using open sans and having the same problem!

Comment: Yep, same here. Open Sans.

Comment: Looks like @Chris O's answer might solve the Open Sans Problem

Comment: Yep using OpenSans on OS X and seeing the same errors. Wonder if Google knows about this

Comment: Guys, did somebody found a solution? I use OpenSans for my mobile application and OpenSans-Regular causes the error.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and the solution was that I was using the wrong subset.  I initially downloaded Open Sans from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) which caused the same error as above.  I downloaded Open Sans from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans) using the MacRoman subset and that fixed my error.

Comment: Worked for me, had to make sure to clean the product first also.