# Font loading error: downloadable font: kern: Too large subtable, table discarded

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, font-family

I am trying to use the "Open sans" font into my web page, and *only* in Firefox, I get this error in console:

> downloadable font: kern: Too large subtable, table discarded

Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    src: url(OpenSans-Semibold.ttf);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This is a problem in Firefox, which cannot handle Open Sans font in its entirety. The bug still exists as of Firefox v 75.0.

They have marked the problem WONTFIX in 2015:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185685

Comment: Actually the bug says the problem is in Open Sans which has a huge kerning tables. So kerning table is trimmed and might not be used. But kerning table is only a rendering hint, doesn't affect rendering that much in case of Open Sans (or at least so Craig Cook says). So the only problem is that it should really be a warning instead of an error.

Answer (score 14):

I did some digging around and the issue seems to be with Open Sans subset itself.

This user (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16041637/4799071) seemed to run into the issue when they downloaded the font from Google Fonts. Try downloading it from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Its not actually a fix: you need to have the latest version of the font, not some archaic iteration. Better download from open-sans.com the latest zip.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day looking at console error messages :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Firefox 85. Try @developthewebz solution and it works.
i downloaded the fontsquirrel web font (woff) and now there is no errors.

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontfacekit/open-sans

Answer (score 0):

Open Sans from fontsquirrel has no full character set e.g. german, french, polish, etc.
I downloaded latest version from Google Fonts and there is no errors.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented by Gelmir, it is important that you download the font from its original source:

https://open-sans.com/

This will solve the problem.

And here is an example how to bind the font into your css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'),
        url(OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6,
        U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193,
        U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```